# Snap extrusion to face

Tags: extrude, snapping, shrinkwrap, mirror-modifier, bisect

i hope someone can maybe share some knowledge here - as you can see in the attached picture i would like the selected edge "snap" to the face (highlighted in blue).

What would be the best way to get this done ?
This is the side of a house and i wanna snap the walls to the roof, is there an "easy" way to  have an extrusion snap to an existing face ?

Thank you for reading this, i appreciate any help.

Cheers

[image]

Comment: You can do this in many ways, which is often the case in blender. 01.  Take the V arch and extrude downwards. Discard original wall. 02. Add a vertical center line to the wall with a loop cut and [shrink wrap] modifier top vertices to your V arch.  03. Mirror Modifier. I am writing in high level terms.  Somone might provide the answer easily to you, in detail, if you wait a little longer.
I am not providing a tutorial because many videos do a better job already.
 Consider archiving your current scene and create a new one for comparison purposes.

Comment: Consider watching a video series on the famous site which has a name that rhymes with noonoob.  Search terms ... Blender Loop Cut Mirror Modifier Shrink Wrap.  You can also search here at BSE.  A video tutorial series might serve you well in the long term.